# Batch script for extracting archives with password list

Tags: command-line, batch, passwords, 7-zip, winrar

I have 30 commonly used passwords. But I can't find any program to automatically try all passwords, so I want to create a batch script to read a txt file containing passwords and try those 30 passwords continuously with UnRAR.exe or 7z.exe. It would also be great if I could add it somewhere easily accessible (like the context menu or send to menu).

I think I need something that makes cmd send the passwords line by line to the batch process.

Also note that some archives may be split into two or more parts, so the script must support multiple extractions.

Comment: That's easy to do. You check for the first password, then check the errorlevel if you get an errorlevel you try the next password else you extract the files. Are you trying to extract your own files or somebody elses files?

Comment: I am trying to extract downloaded archives from my popular websites. I don't know how to check a specific line of a text file and set a variable for it in batch.

Comment: SU isn't a free script writing service.  Show us what you have already done by showing us your batch file.  Tell us where it fails.  Someone here will (for sure) help you through the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a tiny free portable app with many features.

Download the portable version here:
[ExtractNow](https://extractnow.com/#/support)

You can choose your password list in **Settings** -> **Passwords** tab.

For those who don't want to install the shell extension for the context menu feature, make sure these options are enabled in **extractnow.ini**:

```
After Extraction Program Close If Successful=1
Startup Extract Automatically=1
```

Then create a shortcut for extractnow.exe in the **Send to menu** folder. To open **Send-to menu** folder, open **Run (Win+R)** and type **shell:sendto**

done! Now you can select archive files and right click -> **Send to** -> **extractnow**

the **extractnow** will open and automatically extract your archives with the password list and then close automatically.

extractnow also supports [Command Line Parameters](https://extractnow.com/#/documentation#cmdline).